# How to combine joint state publisher with urdf?

Tags: rviz, urdf, joint-state-publisher

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have gone through this tutorial:
[Using urdf with robot_state_publisher](http://wiki.ros.org/urdf/Tutorials/Using%20urdf%20with%20robot_state_publisher)
I wrote my urdf file (for a right arm with fingers) and launched it and it worked and I was able to change everything using the gui. Then I wrote a state_publisher.cpp the same way as the tutorial and a launch file. Now I want everything to work together but I don't know how. In the tutorial it only says that I should run rviz.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/186976/how-to-combine-joint-state-publisher-with-urdf?/) by [Kaddoura](https://answers.ros.org/users/19771/kaddoura/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2014-07-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You also need to compile the C++ node you've written, and then launch the launch file, which will load your URDF onto the parameter server and run the robot_state_publisher and your node.

If you think the tutorial could be clearer about how to do this, feel free to update it with additional instructions.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-07-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Kaddoura](https://answers.ros.org/users/19771/kaddoura/) on 2014-07-18**:
I should launch the launch file of the robot_state_publisher ? and how will this link to my urdf file ? (I have a package for the urdf and another for the robot_state_publisher)

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-07-18**:
The param tag in the launch file loads your URDF into the parameter server, and the robot_state_publisher and other nodes can use it from there.